# Is it foreign income when you sell cryptocurrency and realise a capital gain in the UK?

Tags: taxes, united-kingdom, cryptocurrency, tax-residency, dual-status

Crypto networks are not run by any specific government or group of individuals, compared to other securities like US shares.

So what is the geographical status-quo of cryptocurrency for UK tax purposes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is certainly a complicated topic and it's highly likely that the future will bring us major modification to the official guidance, but as of 2019-2020, the answer is no. Capital gains realised by selling cryptocurrency are NOT foreign income if you're a UK tax resident when you buy and dispose of them.

Read [Cryptoassets for individuals](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/tax-on-cryptoassets/cryptoassets-for-individuals):

> HMRC considers that throughout the time an individual is UK resident, the exchange tokens they hold as beneficial owner will be located in the UK.
>
> HMRC has considered other possibilities, but at this stage in the development of these tokens has found that a residence basis most accurately fits the majority of transactions.
>
> This means a person who holds exchanges tokens is liable to pay UK tax if they are a UK resident and carry out a transaction with their tokens which is subject to UK tax.
>
> ...
>
> Using the residency of the beneficial owner of the exchange tokens to determine the location gives a clear, logical, predictable and objective rule which can be easily applied.

Of course, this gets really, really murky if you're a tax resident of the UK but [domiciled](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/residence-domicile-and-remittance-basis-rules-uk-tax-liability/guidance-note-for-residence-domicile-and-the-remittance-basis-rdr1#how-does-domicile-affect-your-uk-income-tax-and-capital-gains-tax-liability) somewhere else (and potentially a [dual resident](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/dual-residents-hs302-self-assessment-helpsheet)), because your home country might have a different opinion about the location of cryptoassets, so in this case consider talking to a professional tax adviser if you hold big bags of cryptocurrency.